# Call an action at specific time E.g 12:00 am in Java Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a query at specific time every day (24:00). I know about the AlarmManager class. I am trying to implement from the example on the Android website:

```
 private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
 private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
 ...
 alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
 alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

 // Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

 // setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
 // 24 hours.
 alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    1000 * 60 * 1440, alarmIntent);
```

What i am trying to do is instead of calling that alarmIntent to call a method. Is it possible? Or could i make my query in another way?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html try this

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you can only perform needed opareaton in onReceive() method  that is in your AlarmReceiver class. See [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context), android.content.Intent)